# Why Try-> recover returns empty Success in case and condition is not satisfied

Tags: scala

I can't understand why recover returns empty Success in case and filter's condition is not satisfied

```
case class Account(acctNum: Int, balance: Double, interestRace: Double)

   def getAccount()={
    Account(111,7000.0,1.2)
   }

  val withdrowal = 1500

  val acc = Try(getAccount())


  val withdrowalResult = acc map {
    (x: Account) => Account(x.acctNum, x.balance-withdrowal,x.interestRace)
    } filter{
      (x: Account) => x.balance>8000
    }recover{
    case nsee: NoSuchElementException => println("Something went wrong")
  }
  println(withdrowalResult)
```

If I print withdrawarResult, I would get

```
Success(())
```

What should I do If I just want to get Failure and take care of exception if my condition is not satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used recover and it recovered Failure to Success. Given that you just printing in recover and producing no results you have Success[Unit] as a result (Unit is the result of println).

```
....filter(x => x.balance > 8000)
   .recover { case nsee: NoSuchElementException => "Not empty" } 
// res4: scala.util.Try[java.io.Serializable] = Success(Not empty)
```

If you want Failure, just don't do recover:

```
val withdrowalResult = acc map {
    (x: Account) => Account(x.acctNum, x.balance-withdrowal,x.interestRace)
    } filter {
      (x: Account) => x.balance>8000
    }
// Failure(java.util.NoSuchElementException: Predicate does not hold for Account(111,5500.0,1.2))
```

Comment: I did not realise that Success[Unit] is the result of println

Comment: @danny.lesnik by the way, if all you need is somehow indicate that failure has occured, you can attach .onFailure callback with printing.

Comment: I don't think your last comment is correct. Try[Any] doesn't have onFailure callback.

Comment: @danny.lesnik yep, messed up with Future, sorry :-(.

Comment: все нормально, спасибo :)